# Google Maps SDK for iOS version 2.1 download?

Tags: google-places-api, google-maps-sdk-ios

I want to download the latest version (2.1) of the Google Maps (and Google Places) SDK for iOS, but on their website they only have the previous version (2.0.1).

[Step 2: Install the SDK: Install Manually](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/start)

Does anyone know where I can download it? (without using Cocoapods)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check their [podspecs](https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs/blob/master/Specs/a/d/d/GoogleMaps/2.1.1/GoogleMaps.podspec.json).
You can find the link to the framework under the key source.

[Google Maps iOS SDK 2.1.1](https://dl.google.com/dl/cpdc/a703eaeed79249f8/GoogleMaps-2.1.1.tar.gz)